# Save information between VMs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

The main idea what I am trying to do - to have one VM, which has a lot of other VMs. 
The problem is to organize data transportation.

Main VM is connected with a template and other VMs have their own templates.
I use a navigator to change VMs and template selector to change templates.

Navigator:

```
public class NavigationController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<ViewModelBase> _viewModels;

    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set { _currentViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel)); }
    }

    private List<ViewModelBase> _legViewModels;

    private ViewModelBase _legViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase LegViewModel
    {
        get { return _legViewModel; }
        set { _legViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LegViewModel)); }
    }

    public NavigationController()
    {
        _viewModels = new List<ViewModelBase>
        {
            new ViewModelLogin(this),
            new ViewModelPhysicalOverview(this),
            ...list of VMs...
        };

        _currentViewModel = _viewModels.First();

        _legViewModels = new List<ViewModelBase>
        {
            new SFSViewModel(this),
            new BPVHipViewModel(this)
        };

        _legViewModel = _legViewModels.First();
    }

    public void NavigateTo<T>()
    {
        var target = _viewModels.FirstOrDefault(e => e.GetType() == typeof(T));

        if (target != null)
            CurrentViewModel = target;
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        //если PropertyChanged не нулевое - оно будет разбужено
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My main VM:

```
public BPVHipViewModel LeftBPVHip { get; protected set; }
public SFSViewModel LeftSFS { get; protected set; }

public BPVHipViewModel RightBPVHip { get; protected set; }
public SFSViewModel RightSFS { get; protected set; }

public ViewModelAddPhysical(NavigationController controller) : base(controller)
    {
        LeftBPVHip = new BPVHipViewModel(Controller);
        RightBPVHip = new BPVHipViewModel(Controller);

        LeftSFS = new SFSViewModel(Controller);
        RightSFS = new SFSViewModel(Controller);

        Controller = controller;
        base.HasNavigation = false;

        ToRightBPVHipCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Controller.LegViewModel = RightBPVHip;
                Controller.NavigateTo<LegPartViewModel>();
            }
        );

        ToLeftBPVHipCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Controller.LegViewModel = LeftBPVHip;
                Controller.NavigateTo<LegPartViewModel>();
            }
        );

        ToLeftSFSCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Controller.LegViewModel = LeftSFS;
                Controller.NavigateTo<LegPartViewModel>();
            }
        );

        ToRightSFSCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Controller.LegViewModel = RightSFS;
                Controller.NavigateTo<LegPartViewModel>();
            }
        );

    }
```

So before I go to another VM and change my screen, I do

Controller.LegViewModel = RightSFS;

and I thought if I change something in RightSFS - it will keep changes after  returning to main VM. But I guess it doesn't work like this.

In children I have:

```
private bool _isEmpty = true;
    public bool IsEmpty {
        get
        {
            return _isEmpty;
        }
        protected set {
            _isEmpty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEmpty");
        }
    }

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsEmpty) return "Edit";
            else return "Fill";
        }
    }
```

And a fn that fires before I return to parent screen:

```
SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
            {
                IsEmpty = false;
                Controller.NavigateTo<ViewModelAddPhysical>();
            }
        );
```

so I want a button from main template to show if we already have visited child screen, in this case I want "Edit" text. But it returns "Fill" all the time, 'cause IsEmpty doesn't change from true to false for him and I don't understand how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MessageBus pattern, it was perfect solution for me

```
class Subscription
{
    public object Instance { get; set; }

    public Action<object, object> Handler;
}

public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton

    private static readonly MessageBus _instance = new MessageBus();

    public static MessageBus Default => _instance;

    private MessageBus()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Action<object, object>>> _hadlersMap 
        = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<object, object>>>();

    public void Call(string name, object sender, object data)
    {
        List<Action<object, object>> handlers;

        if(!_hadlersMap.TryGetValue(name.ToUpper(), out handlers))
            return;

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
             handler?.Invoke(sender,data);
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(string name, Action<object, object> handler)
    {
        name = name.ToUpper();

        List<Action<object, object>> handlers;

        if (!_hadlersMap.TryGetValue(name, out handlers))
        {
            handlers = new List<Action<object, object>>{ handler }; 
            _hadlersMap.Add(name, handlers);
        }
        else
        {
            handlers.Add(handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, you are trying to invent a wheel of your own. It's done, multiple times. Every MVVM framework outthere has built-in navigation.

Take a look at ReactiveUI (great framework) [samples](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing), they are doing exactly what you need.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ninject;
using ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing.Views;
using Splat;

namespace ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing.ViewModels
{
    /* COOLSTUFF: What is the AppBootstrapper?
     * 
     * The AppBootstrapper is like a ViewModel for the WPF Application class.
     * Since Application isn't very testable (just like Window / UserControl), 
     * we want to create a class we can test. Since our application only has
     * one "screen" (i.e. a place we present Routed Views), we can also use 
     * this as our IScreen.
     * 
     * An IScreen is a ViewModel that contains a Router - practically speaking,
     * it usually represents a Window (or the RootFrame of a WinRT app). We 
     * should technically create a MainWindowViewModel to represent the IScreen,
     * but there isn't much benefit to split those up unless you've got multiple
     * windows.
     * 
     * AppBootstrapper is a good place to implement a lot of the "global 
     * variable" type things in your application. It's also the place where
     * you should configure your IoC container. And finally, it's the place 
     * which decides which View to Navigate to when the application starts.
     */

    public class AppBootstrapper : ReactiveObject, IScreen
    {
        public RoutingState Router { get; private set; }

        public AppBootstrapper(IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, RoutingState testRouter = null)
        {
            Router = testRouter ?? new RoutingState();
            dependencyResolver = dependencyResolver ?? Locator.CurrentMutable;

            // Bind 
            RegisterParts(dependencyResolver);

            // TODO: This is a good place to set up any other app 
            // startup tasks, like setting the logging level
            LogHost.Default.Level = LogLevel.Debug;

            // Navigate to the opening page of the application
            // you can set any property of this new VM to transport data
            Router.Navigate.Execute(new WelcomeViewModel(this));
        }

        private void RegisterParts(IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver)
        {
            dependencyResolver.RegisterConstant(this, typeof(IScreen));

            dependencyResolver.Register(() => new WelcomeView(), typeof(IViewFor<WelcomeViewModel>));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I guess it's too complicated for me to understand now

Comment: give a try later, it will make your live 10 times easier :)

Answer (score -1):

So I have never seem things be done this way. Have you looked at Windsor. I believe dependency injection and inversion of control could improve the scalability here. As far as suggestions go.

There is a lot of instantiation going on in many different places in the code here. Maybe creating a factory to handle all the new-ing up. IOC would help with that as well. You could place your list of models globally. `App.Current.Properties[ "someVm" ] = vmInstance;` if you are wanting to save the vm state. 
Another way to persist the vm state would of course be to make that vm a singleton ensuring that when called it returns that only instance if already exists or instantiates if not.
Finally, I have persisted vm state upon unloading and reading state from somewhere upon loading. This is common and many default controls do this.

Comment: Sorry, it's too much information. Maybe you can show some links with examples?

Comment: Title says you want to save data between vm's. Singleton will do just that  for application lifetime and serialization of data upon views unloading event and reading or deserialization upon views loading event is also a common way to save vm state. As will persisting to application properties. Check out MVVMLight. I use it in most all my WPF projects and this offers view model locator and a navigation scheme. links [ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348545(v=vs.100).aspx ] - [ http://www.mvvmlight.net/ ] - [ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx ]

Comment: Oh and MvvmLight gives a DelegateCommand implementation called RelayCommand that is generic and easy to use.   `nuget.exe install mvvlight` .